# Graph library for iPhone and Android

Tags: php, jquery, iphone, android, mobile

All,

I have been using JQuery Mobile Framework to develop a mobile version of my website accessible from iPhone and Android devices. I am unable to find a single graph library that works on both these devices using the mobile framework.

Did anybody get this working? if so, please suggest some ideas.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

http://code.google.com/intl/et-EE/apis/chart/docs/chart_wizard.html should work on both as it's image based.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by graphs? The term actually means a [set of nodes and connecting edges](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_%28mathematics%29) - but most people use ot to refer to the kind of numerical plots you might do using a spreadsheet.

If it's the former, then take a look at [graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/). This is a standalone executable which creates images from a simple definition language - its simple to [integrate this within your PHP code.](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/6688-PHP-Generate-call-graphs-of-PHP-code-with-GraphViz.html)

Since you mentioned PHP, you might want to have a look at [jpgraph](http://jpgraph.net/). It's a php library which creates images of plots.

However if you want to develop an offline application then you'll need a tool which runs in javascript, e.g. [plotkit](http://www.liquidx.net/plotkit/). There are more listed [here](http://sixrevisions.com/javascript/20-fresh-javascript-data-visualization-libraries/).

C.